# Can Figwheel evaluate ClojureScript code when a resource file changes?

Tags: clojure, markdown, clojurescript, figwheel

I have a macro that slurps a markdown file from resources.
It provides a convenient way to provide some content.
But when I edit the markdown file, Figwheel has no way to know that it needs to re-evaluate the macro.

Putting the markdown in a string inside a cljs file is undesirable because strings with newlines get indented by most Clojure editors, and this causes the markdown to be incorrect (leading spaces are meaningful in markdown).

Is there a way to detect/refresh when the markdown file changes? Or a better solution?

Here is a basic example of what I am trying to do:
https://github.com/timothypratley/figwheel-watch-markdown-example

Answer (score 2):

Figwheel's configs allow you to add [`::watch-paths`](https://github.com/bhauman/lein-figwheel/blob/c80c96188a99a09e94e236e4242cea9c38231343/sidecar/src/figwheel_sidecar/schemas/config.clj#L529) which trigger reloading when modification events come up from the file system. You can also use [`::hawk-options`](https://github.com/bhauman/lein-figwheel/blob/c80c96188a99a09e94e236e4242cea9c38231343/sidecar/src/figwheel_sidecar/schemas/config.clj#L290) to poll the files looking for changes, which apparently might be necessary in some environments.

Comment: Thanks for the idea... I couldn't get it working. https://github.com/timothypratley/figwheel-watch-markdown-example <-- setting the watch-paths doesn't cause recompilation or reloading to occur. Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: @TimothyPratley did you try to set [`log-writer`](https://github.com/bhauman/lein-figwheel/blob/e47da1658a716f83888e5a5164ee88e59b2d8c1e/sidecar/src/figwheel_sidecar/components/file_system_watcher.clj#L26-L28) in `figwheel-server-options`? It could hint what might be going on with the file system watcher.

Comment: You're right, this one seems to be harder than that on account of the clj-reloading system not recognizing that the clj file with the macro has a dependency on non-Clojure files so needs recompiling when they change.
Gonna try to look some more at that tomorrow.